# Wordpress Woocommerce External Product - External link open in popup window when image clicked instead of product page. Same as button click

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone know how to make it so that when you click the image on the Product Archive page of a External/Affiliate product that the link will open in a popup exactly like it does when you click the button below the image. Currently when you click the image it goes to the product page.

I searched everywhere I could but I could not find how to do this.

Here is my site if you want to see what I mean. Please help!

http://danielo79.sg-host.com/product-category/uncategorized/

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this jQuery function:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $( 'li.product.product-type-external' ).each( function() {

        if ( $( this ).find( 'a.button' ).hasClass( 'product_type_external' ) ) {

            $( this ).find( 'a:not(.product_type_external)' ).attr( 'href', $( this ).find( 'a.button.product_type_external' ).attr( 'href' ) );

        }

    } );

} );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Where would I put this code?

Comment: Put it on the Elementor custom code.

EDIT: I put single quotes on Line 7.